# SQL files not executing on Oracle 12C Database startup

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose

I am using Oracle Database Enterprise Edition and this is my docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
      image: store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
      restart: "unless-stopped"
      ports:
        - 1523:1521
        - 5501:5500
      volumes:
        - ./setup-scripts:/opt/oracle/scripts/setup
        - ./dump:/opt/oracle/dump
      environment: 
        - "ORACLE_PWD=oracle"
```

When I use `docker-compose up` my sql files are copied to `/opt/oracle/scripts/setup` but the sql files are not executed. What could be the possible reason ? "ORACLE_PWD=oracle" doesn't seem to work also. I have to use the default password `Oradoc_db1`

Comment: How exactly did you build `store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1`?

Comment: I used `docker login` first . Then it pulled from the hub

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://github.com/gvenzl/oci-oracle-xe . Here it is explained how to run scripts at startup.

Comment: still doesn't work